# How to set the id attribute of a WebElement?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

According to the selenium API doc, there is a function `getAttribute` but there is no `setAttribute`

Ideally I would like to be able to do the following:

```
element.set_attribute('id', 'abcd')
```

What I want to achieve is to set the id of a WebElement during a test.

I am using driver 2.44 and it does not support `execute_script` with argument

Comment: Can you provide some `html` of the element you are dealing with?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot set the attribute of an element using Selenium. Primarily, it is for automating web applications for testing purposes.

Selenium does allow executing javascript on a web page though.

See below examples:

You can execute arbitrary javascript to find an element and as long as you return a DOM Element, it will be automatically converted to a WebElement object.

```
WebElement element = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return $('.cheese')[0]");
```

Finding all the input elements to the every label on a page:

```
List<WebElement> labels = driver.findElements(By.tagName("label"));
List<WebElement> inputs = (List<WebElement>) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
    "var labels = arguments[0], inputs = []; for (var i=0; i < labels.length; i++){" +
    "inputs.push(document.getElementById(labels[i].getAttribute('for'))); } return inputs;", labels);
```

For some more information, you can go through the [Selenium Documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp)
, which is very precise.